# Blocking Business Email Compromise (BEC) emails

Tags: email, phishing, spam

I am recieving phishing emails like the one depicted below, with the sender being 
a legit member of our organization. How can I block this kind of email? What should be done? Is malwarebytes capable of detecting the issue?

[image: Phishing mail.]

Comment: This is not malware, so malwarebytes is not going to help.

Comment: Email server-based content inspection is what you want. What to look for, though, depends on the normal patterns of your business.

Comment: The email sender might be legit, but did it come from your server or from an external server?

Comment: thanks Schroeder. it came from an external. so what would be the direction to suppress this?

Comment: Maybe SPF DKIM DMARC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sending account uses an alias that is an internal account, then it is easy to detect and block.

```
From: Ali@example.com <bad@evil.com>
```

Each server will have their own methods to do this.

If the external server is spoofing an internal email, then you need to employ SPF, DMARC, DKIM.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to technical methods of preventing the phishing emails from being received, user education is practical and effective in this case.

You can communicate with your company the specific type of phishing emails that you are receiving and how to identify that they are phishing emails, which helps inoculate them from falling for the tricks used when they are targeted. Having them share phishing emails they receive with their colleagues also helps.

At the same time, explaining some simple rules such as

> always verify payments in person or on the phone

can stop many of these attacks before any money is lost.

Comment: Education and finance protocols are highly effective once an email is received, but the question is about how to block the emails. Preventing users from needing to think or make choices is always the better option.